# Anonymous interface implementation in php

Tags: java, php, interface

In Java we can do like this..

```java
interface Inter {
    public void run()
}

class Test {
    public Test(Inter inter){
        inter.run();
    }
}

new Test(new Inter() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Some Task;
    }
}
```

But in php I got error while doing like this. Isn't it possible to do this in php?

Comment: can you show your PHP code and tell us which PHP version are you using ? 5.4, 5.6, 7 ? Anyway, you definitelly cannot instantiate an interface in PHP, like you do here with `new Inter()`

Comment: Ok Thanks , i just wanted to know if i am missing this feature in php,

Answer (score 10):

A little late, but you can do this in php:

```
new Test(new class implements Inter {
    public function run()
    {
        // Some Task;
    }
});
```